# How to sum two dataframe columns based on another column value

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

[Dataframe head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV0oj.png)
I am stuck on a personal data analysis project with pandas using the English premier league dataset linked below. The HY column stands for home yellow cards and AY stands for Away yellow cards.

How do I find which team received the most yellow/red cards for the entire season? I have tried groupby HomeTeam/AwayTeam columns but the result is not quite what it should be.

Edit: I have tried this but it is very verbose:
df.groupby("HomeTeam")['HY'].sum().sort_values(ascending =False) + df.groupby("AwayTeam")['HY'].sum().sort_values(ascending =False)

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/irkaal/english-premier-league-results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['cards'] = df['AY']+df['HY']

u = df.groupby('teamname')['cards'].max()
```

Comment: The only way I have solved it so far is like this but it is very verbose so I think there is a simpler solution.                                                                                             
df.groupby("HomeTeam")['HY'].sum().sort_values(ascending =False) + df.groupby("AwayTeam")['HY'].sum().sort_values(ascending =False)

Comment: You can use max method and it is very easier

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, you may find it beneficial reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)